# ScrollView in content of DrawerLayout prevents the drawer to be opened by swiping

Tags: android, scrollview, navigation-drawer

When I put `ScrollView` into the content of a `DrawerLayout`, I am nolonger able to open the drawer by swiping from the side.

Activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The menu_main content view -->
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
        android:name="com.gumtree.androidapp.DrawerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In Activity's `onCreate` I add a fragment which has following layout:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/headline_text_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/detail_text_padding"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/description_text_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/detail_text_padding"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Without the `ScrollView` everything works fine and I am able to open the drawer by swiping from the side. However when I add the `ScrollView`, it stops working.

Comment: I tested this using the sample app provided by the Android documentation and it does not seem to make a difference. I added a scrollview to the fragments layout and the side menu slides out perfectly. I tested this on a Nexus 4 device. Here is a link to the sample application i am referring to (I also pasted your layout into the fragment and it worked fine): http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I'm guessing there is something somewhere else in your code that may be causing the weird behavior.

Comment: You are right, DejanRistic. The problem was related to silly named ID of content FrameLayout. I shouldn't have used the system ID (`android.R.id.content`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was silly named ID of `FrameLayout` used as content container of `DrawerLayout`. I used system ID (`android.R.id.content`) which caused that the content fragment was put on the top of all other views - even the drawer.

It also caused fragment's `layout` to overlap the drawer and - related to this question - blocked the drawer from receiving touch events. The touch events were taken by fragment's `ScrollView`.

Conclusion: **DO NOT USE SYSTEM IDs** (android.R.*) **WHERE IT IS NOT NEEDED.**

I just wanted it to look nice and clean.. Silly me :)